# Getting JSON feature id on OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geojson, json

I'm projecting some features using JSON format on OpenLayers. I need to get the id from the feature (not the OpenLayers' id but the one in the JSON file). The file looks something like this.

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{ "type": "Feature", "id": 7655199, "properties": {"power":"line","wires":"NA","frequency":"NA","voltage":"380000","operator":"NA","cables":"6"}, "geometry": {"type":"LineString", "coordinates":[[8.5310699,49.8531139],[8.5289255,49.8563936],[8.5268405,49.8594383]]}} etc..
```

Now in OpenLayers I'm trying to do something like this.

```
var feature_col = gjson.read(ReadFile(json_path + file[i]) , "FeatureCollection");
//Readfile is just a function for reading the file, what a surprise... :P
var power_res = feature_col[0].attributes.power;
var id_res = feature_col[0].id) //for the first feature
```

So the value in power_res gives line which is correct. However, the value in `id_res` is something like `OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_362` and I need the id in this case to be `7655199`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `var id_res = feature_col[0].attributes.id` instead `var id_res = feature_col[0].id`.

## UPDATE

`feature_col[0].fid`
See my live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/XbRgR/).

Comment: It doesn't work. It is undefined. Thanks anyway

Comment: I've modified my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it. feature_col[0].fid is the way. It results into 7655199. FID not ID.

source: http://chitraswiki.blogspot.de/2009/11/getting-attributes-of.html